# Jquery printelement

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery print element, How could I include a different style sheet for printing ?

```
$("selector").printElement(
{
    overrideElementCSS:[
       'thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css',
       { href:'thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css',media:'print'}
    ]
});
```

What is the difference between *thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css* and
*thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css*?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin. However, my guess is that the plain string URL will be used for display and printing, while the object with the `media: 'print'` option will only be used when printing. But as I say, that's just a guess.

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the plugin's [documentation](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/), it seems that:

- `thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css` is used for displaying your page in the browser's window, whereas
- `thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css` is *only* used for the Print mode.

This means that anything you define in `thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css` will *not* appear in the normal browsing of the page in the browser.

And to answer your first question (*How could I include a different style sheet for printing?*):

You simply need to define the style for Print `thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css`.

Please let me know if I can elaborate on any of the above. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this plugin, but from the description given on the [plugin's site](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/):

---

Type: `Array of Strings | Array of $.fn.printElement.cssElement | Boolean`
Default: `null`
Description: `Can be one of the following 3 options:`

1. : boolean (pass true for stripping all css linked)
2. : array of $.fn.printElement.cssElement (s)
3. : array of strings with paths to alternate css files (optimized for print

---

It seems like this option is used to remove/override any existing css files that are applied to the page.

So, what I believe this code block is doing is showing techniques `2.` and `3.` for removing/overriding css in the current page.

```
$("selector").printElement(
{
    overrideElementCSS:[
       'thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css',
       { href:'thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css',media:'print'}
    ]
});
```